# How to add new win form in project C#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have existing project. I tried to add new empty form in this, but I have limited choose of windows form that mean to inheriting. But I need just simple form.

[image]

I use VS 2017

[image]

Comment: What are you going to do exactly? you want to add a new winform project to your solution?

Comment: Yes, just new form  without inheritance

Comment: Click on "Visual C# Items"

Comment: I clicked, there is nothing there. see pic attachment

Comment: Have you installed the required components (take a look in the the Visual Studio 2017 Install Application)

Comment: What do you mean?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems like you didn't install the required components. To do this, close VS, run your *Visual Studio Installer* (you probably installed VS through it), click modify for your VS Version and make sure that *.Net desktop development* is checked:[image: checked component]

Then launch the installation by hitting *Modify* and start VS again. If you now want to create a new Project it should look something like that:[image: project view]

Comment: Re-Running the VS Community 2019 Installer and selecting the .Net Desktop Development option added another 5 options to the Add-> New Item-> Windows Forms  options, including a blank Window form.

Answer (score 1):

**Try this**

1. Open Solution Explorer
2. Right click on your Project's Name.
3. Add.
4. Windows Form.

If you still don't see it, you might be missing the **Dot Net desktop development Component.**