# VS2019: WF: Add Second Form don't work, it tries to add a class

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I created a windows form application and it has a form1.cs file which has also designer mode.
but when I try to add->"new form", then the VS2019 only adds an empty class! not a new form.
Am I Missing something?
[image]

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add new win form in project C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45653884/how-to-add-new-win-form-in-project-c)

Comment: If the duplicate does not help, you can try to repair VS setup. Else to uninstall VS and reinstall it. If it does not work, you can try a full cleanup: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62703847/why-does-my-visual-studio-closes-automatically-without-any-errors/62713351#62713351. Else you can try to reinstall Windows from nothing, unless you have a O&O DiskImage or a Macrium Reflect or anything else to restore from your daily incremental backups.

Comment: Tax So much, the problem solved by installing ".Net desktop development"
but I think it is a bug because I could create a windows form application but I could not add the form!